# mono mkbundle : what are mono_mkbundle_init() and JIT inizialization?

Tags: mono, embed, bundle, jit, mkbundle

I tried to bundle my app with mkbundle command due to this help:

http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications#Bundles

but I don't understand this part of this doc:

`With -c, the further option --nomain will generate the host.c file without a main method so that 
you can embed it as a library in an existing native application in which you are embedding the Mono 
runtime yourself. Just call mono_mkbundle_init() before initializing the JIT to make the bundled 
assemblies available.`

which is absolutely what I need to do!
I also looked up this doc:
http://man.he.net/man1/mkbundle2

again the same part:

```
You may also use mkbundle to generate a bundle you can use when  embed-
   ding  the Mono runtime in a native application.  In that case, use both
   the -c and --nomain options.  The resulting host.c file will not have a
   main() function.  Call mono_mkbundle_init() before initializing the JIT
   in your code so that the bundled assemblies are available to the embed-
   ded runtime.
```

I don't really know what are `mono_mkbundle_init()` and `initializing the JIT`...
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

mono_mkbundle_init() is a function generated by mkbundle in host.c 
"initializing the JIT" should be mono function mono_jit_init()
so the meaning is that, link the generated c file in your native application and invoke mono_mkbundle_init() before invoking mono_jit_init()